# Yocto conflicting error while building rootfs

Tags: yocto, conflict, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

I am building for the board LS1046ARDB.

I added a recipe on top of the yocto given recipes, the recipe I created has a dependency of libusb I added the dependency and it compiles well, but when I am trying to build rootfs I am getting the conflicting error of libusb, I tried browsing online this error I cant able to solve. Can you please help me with the issue.

I am posting the error log for the reference.

```
ERROR: ls-image-main-22.04.1-r0 do_rootfs: Could not invoke dnf. Command '/home/labuser/NEERAJ/ASK_1046/DISTRO/build_ls1046ardb/tmp/work/ls1046ardb-fsl-linux/ls-image-main/22.04.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/dnf -v --allowerasing --rpmverbosity=info -y -c /home/labuser/NEERAJ/ASK_1046/DISTRO/build_ls1046ardb/tmp/work/ls1046ardb-fsl-linux/ls-image-main/22.04.1-r0/rootfs/etc/dnf/dnf.conf --setopt=exit-on-err=false --setopt=reposdir=/home/labuser/NEERAJ/ASK_1046/DISTRO/build_ls1046ardb/tmp/work/ls1046ardb-fsl-linux/ls-image-main/22.04.1-r0/rootfs/etc/yum.repos.d --installroot=/home/labuser/NEERAJ/ASK_1046/DISTRO/build_ls1046ardb/tmp/work/ls1046ardb-fsl-linux/ls-image-main/22.04.1-r0/rootfs --setopt=logdir=/home/labuser/NEERAJ/ASK_1046/DISTRO/build_ls1046ardb/tmp/work/ls1046ardb-fsl-linux/ls-image-main/22.04.1-r0/temp --repofrompath=oe-repo,/home/labuser/NEERAJ/ASK_1046/DISTRO/build_ls1046ardb/tmp/work/ls1046ardb-fsl-linux/ls-image-main/22.04.1-r0/oe-rootfs-repo --nogpgcheck install autobridge blktrace can-utils cdx cmm cpufrequtils distrobootscr dpa-app fci fio i2c-tools iozone3 iperf2 iperf3 ipsec-demo ipsec-tools kernel-devicetree kernel-image kernel-modules libcli libpkcs11 linuxptp lmbench lmsensors-sensors makedevs mmc-utils netdata netperf openssl-engines packagegroup-fsl-tools-core packagegroup-fsl-tools-extended pciutils perf qcom rt-tests secure-obj secure-obj-module strongswan sysfsutils tcpdump ubuntu-main ubuntu-main-dbg ubuntu-main-dev ubuntu-main-doc udev-extraconf udev-rules-qoriq usbutils watchdog' returned 1:
Main config did not have a exit-on-err attr. before setopt
DNF version: 4.11.1
cachedir: /home/labuser/NEERAJ/ASK_1046/DISTRO/build_ls1046ardb/tmp/work/ls1046ardb-fsl-linux/ls-image-main/22.04.1-r0/rootfs/var/cache/dnf
Added oe-repo repo from /home/labuser/NEERAJ/ASK_1046/DISTRO/build_ls1046ardb/tmp/work/ls1046ardb-fsl-linux/ls-image-main/22.04.1-r0/oe-rootfs-repo
Main config did not have a exit-on-err attr. before setopt
User-Agent: falling back to 'libdnf': could not detect OS or basearch
repo: using cache for: oe-repo
oe-repo: using metadata from Fri 01 Mar 2024 01:29:54 PM UTC.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Fri 01 Mar 2024 01:29:55 PM UTC.
--> Starting dependency resolution
--> Finished dependency resolution
**Error:
Problem: package ubuntu-main-22.04.1-r0.aarch64 conflicts with libusb-1.0-0 provided by libusb-1.0-0-1.0.26-r0.aarch64
- package ubuntu-main-22.04.1-r0.aarch64 obsoletes libusb-1.0-0 provided by libusb-1.0-0-1.0.26-r0.aarch64
- package qcom-1.0-r0.ls1046ardb requires libusb-1.0.so.0()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- conflicting requests
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)**

ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/labuser/NEERAJ/ASK_1046/DISTRO/build_ls1046ardb/tmp/work/ls1046ardb-fsl-linux/ls-image-main/22.04.1-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.3213332
ERROR: Task (/home/labuser/NEERAJ/ASK_1046/DISTRO/sources/meta-nxp-desktop/recipes-fsl/images/ls-image-main.bb:do_rootfs) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 4421 tasks of which 4409 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
/home/labuser/NEERAJ/ASK_1046/DISTRO/sources/meta-nxp-desktop/recipes-fsl/images/ls-image-main.bb:do_rootfs
Summary: There were 5 WARNING messages.
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

I tried excluding libusb, in recipie file, local.conf but still I am getting this error

Comment: seems like your custom recipe depends on the wrong package. Can you post your RDEPENDS?

Comment: There are no RDEPENDS.